# How to generate averages with data already inputted in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, sum, average

I can't figure out how to calculate the sum of data in order to return an average, after I've entered all data into a for loop. I don't know what to put after "`protein_sum =`" to make this work. This is for a uni assignment. Any solutions?

I've tried using the `sum()` function but returns the error 'int' object is not iterable, and I'm very confused. This is on python 3.

```py
for number_of_patients in range(1, number_of_patients + 1)
    protein = int(input("Enter protein(g) requirement for patient: ")

protein_sum = 
avg_protein = protein_sum / number_of_patients
print(avg_protein)
```

I expect the user to input 'n' patients and their respective protein requirements and return the average of protein required.

Eg. If there were three patients and the user inputted 10, 20 and 15 as the protein amounts, I expect the program to return 15 as the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on input format of user, If user has entered all protiens in new line then this code will work:

```
proteins=[] 
number_of_patients=int(input("Enter Number of patients: "))
for number_of_patients in range(1, number_of_patients + 1):
    protein=int( input("Enter protein(g) requirement for patient: ") )
    proteins.append(protein)
protein_sum = sum(proteins)
avg_protein = protein_sum / number_of_patients
print(avg_protein)
```

Else if user has entered all protein in single line seperated by space then this will work:

```
number_of_proteins=int(input())
proteins=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
protein_sum=sum(proteins)
avg=protein_sum/number_of_proteins
print(avg)
```

Comment: I tried your idea, but 'proteins' returns an error of not being defined. Then 'protein' returns the error 'int' object has no attribute append

Comment: here is your updated solution-https://ideone.com/gRNOmI, Hope it'll help, Its my first answer on stack overflow , Do upvote and accept it if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this. Just sum the numbers with the total of the previous values.

```
protein_sum = 0
for number_of_patients in range(1, number_of_patients + 1){
    protein = int(input("Enter protein(g) requirement for patient: ")
    protein_sum += protein
}

avg_protein = protein_sum / number_of_patients
print(avg_protein)
```

Comment: I am using a for loop, with if and else statements, because I have to do the same thing with carbohydrates, fat and kilojoules, all being set out in the code in the same way

Comment: If these are to be calculated separately, then you need to consider each of the different variables. Like protein_sum. The same is true for all of them.

Comment: I tried your idea and the result returned is incorrect, as the average 10 and 20 is 15, and not the returned 10

Comment: Please share the code you used. So I can find the problem.

Comment: I would love to, but how do I do that? I'm very much a novice

Comment: The easiest way is to put your code file on a link. Then share that link in the comment. use https://filebin.net/

Comment: You must consider a counter for each variable. After each entry, add one number to it and then use it to calculate the average.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you please show me instead of describing?

Comment: I did the C++ and it was ok, but I did not have an environment for testing it in Python. However, I tried to give you the code to Python. If there is a problem, see the C ++ code and return it to Python.  check this link in python https://ideone.com/YR4PSt and this link in C++ https://ideone.com/VDeUIU.